# Apache: Allow Certain Users only from specified subnet

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, apache2

I have a requirement to change some Apache 2.4 authentication so that *most* users can access the website from anywhere, but certain users (who can be identified in a number of ways, but an LDAP group would be the easiest) can only be permitted access from a certain IP address subnet. (Authentication is via OIDC module plus ldap groups.)

(A simplified version of what) the current Apache config is

```
<RequireAll>
    <RequireAny>
        Require valid-user
        Require claim aud:apache123.company.com
    </RequireAny>
    Require ldap-attribute companyMemberOf="ALL_USERS_OF_THIS_TOOL"
</RequireAll>
```

I'm not sure how best to implement this negative clause for a certain group.

I had to use the workaround [discussed here](https://serverfault.com/a/985000/302088) with a dummy `Require all granted` clause to avoid the `RequireAll directive contains only negative authorization directives` error.

I think adding this would do it but I'd appreciate the feedback. Because with this kind of thing I can easily imagine somebody writing "you'd think that would work but it doesn't because...", or "yes that works, but it's really not the right way to do it because..."

```
    <RequireAny>
        <RequireAll>
            RequireNone ldap-attribute companyMemberOf="RESTRICTED_GROUP"
            # Just to keep Apache happy
            Require all granted
         </RequireAll>
        RequireIp 10.10.0.0/22
    </RequireAny>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the boolean logic of the rules as they would stand:

```
<RequireAll>
### First, and foremost, users need to be Apache users.
    Require ldap-attribute companyMemberOf="ALL_APACHE_USERS"

### AND
    <RequireAny>
##### Users need to be either valid
        Require valid-user
##### Or have the appropiate claim.
        Require claim aud:apache123.company.com
    </RequireAny>

### AND
    <RequireAny>
##### Finally, users need to NOT have the companyMemberOf="RESTRICTED_GROUP" attribute
        Require not ldap-attribute companyMemberOf="RESTRICTED_GROUP"
##### Or be accessing from the 10.10.0.0/22 subnet.
        Require ip 10.10.0.0/22
    </RequireAny>
</RequireAll>
```

Logic dictates that the last block would evaluate to true (and therefore granting access) only if:

- a). Users ARE coming from the subnet,
- or b). Users ARE NOT restricted.

So, I believe the rules should satisfy your needs.

Note, however, the space between "Require" and "ip" and using "not" instead of "None"; the  directive is used to enclose a set of directives, analogically to  or .

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my problem after some testing and with some new information from https://serverfault.com/questions/984997/apache-2-4-require-exclude-ip-range . There is some funny syntax associated with negatives.

Comment: I did think that this approach was somehow "reverseward", LOL, but couldn't think a "forward" way to do it, in order to keep it cleaner, clearer and easier to maintain.

Comment: Also, have you tried with "Require not" instead of "RequireNone"?. The way I wrote it, shouldn't throw AH01624 (since "require ip" is not negative).

Comment: "negative Require directive has no effect in <RequireAny> directive"